# How to get the repeating numeric part of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

`print_r($_POST['Receipt']['name'])`

gave me an array like this

```
Array (
    [Donations] => Array (
        [name] => Donations
    )
    [Fees] => Array (
        [ledger] => Fees
    )
    [100] => Array (
        [amount] => 100
    )
    [Others] => Array (
        [name] => Others
    )
)
```

here the two repeating numeric values 100 and fees(they are both the values the field amount and ledger respectively) is what i want to store in an array. I tried some thing like this

```
foreach ($_POST['Receipt']['name'] as $item)
        {   

            if (isset($item['amount']))
            {
                $amount[]= $item['amount'];
            }
            if (isset($item['ledger']))
            {
                $ledger[]= $item['ledger'];
            }

        }
```

but $ledger[] and $amount[] will not store repeating values of them. for amounnt[], it would store only the 100 in `[amount] => 100` and will not store the 100 in `[100] => Array` How can i store the repeating values in this array?

Comment: one of the `100`'s is a key, the other is a value. They're *not* repeating values

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach ($_POST['Receipt']['name'] as $item)
    {   

        if (isset($item['100']))
        {
            $amount[]= $item['100']['amount'];
        }
        if (isset($item['fees']))
        {
            $ledger[]= $item['fees']['ledger'];
        }

    }
```